# how to use temporary database for every user in django

Tags: python, django

so i am learning Django and making a todo application but i am stuck with a problem. I am storing every task on sqlite3 database(default by django) with models but when anyone store any task it is also visible to other person also how can i fix that?
if you have any alternative solution for that you can also tell that like how to use cookies or anything

```
models.py:-

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Task(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Not if you add a field with the `user` that is supposed to look at it, and filter accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store who the task belongs to,

```
class Task(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

You will have to store the user when creating/updating the Task 
For instance,

```
task = Task.objects.create(title=title, user=user)
```

Now when you need to show the tasks, show only relavant tasks

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```